# Google Sheets: Print output in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

If I use the formula: `=UNIQUE(A1:A9)` on the B1 cell, the column B will be filled with the unique appearances from A1 to A9. In other words: it will remove duplicates.

The problem is that if I want to order from A to Z of the column C, the formula will be moved to some other place, so it will stop working.

My workaround so far has been this:

[image: screenshot of my workaround]

However, you will be agree that it's not the most elegant solution.

I'd like to know if it's possible to use a formula in Z1 to print the output starting from Z3.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to use a formula in Z1 to print the output starting from Z3.

use in Z1:

```
={""; ""; UNIQUE(I3:I313)}
```

Comment: Nice! After understanding your formula, I've used the following formula instead (used in Z2): `={"Without duplicates"; UNIQUE(I3:I)}`